# Java, Infinite loop- multiples of 2 only

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am asked to print multiples of 2 only  with a never ending loop.

Attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Infiniteloop {

    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        int number,x;
        System.out.print("Enter a number");

        number=input.nextInt();
        if(number%2==0)
        {
            while(number>=0)
            {
                x= (++number);
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can only use  while-loop.   So I tried to set the remainder of 2  equal to zero. I tried using the counter but it doesnt increment it. Keeps printing out zeros. I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Alan, clearly.  But he/she has already given it a good try it looks like.  So, I feel it would be ok to help.

Comment: It needs to print  multiples of integer  2 such as 2,4, 16, 32.

Comment: @zrn, I get that it prints multiples of 2.  But how is it getting the numbers to check for divisibility by 2?  Does the user input every number?  Or does he user input a starting number, and then you print every multiple of two above that?

Comment: @zrn The sequence of integers you provided in your comment (2,4,16,32) seems to indicate that you need to output _powers_ of 2 not _multiples_. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: The user just prints a starting number and then it goes on from there.

Comment: @phuibers. no, multiples of 2.

Comment: @phuibers, you are right. my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing that you want to prompt the user for a start number and then print all the following even numbers:

```
number = input.nextInt(); //read the input
number += number % 2; //if input is odd, add 1
while (true)
{
   System.out.println (number);
   number += 2;
}
```

Supposing you want to check for even numbers:

```
while (true)
{
  number = input.nextInt();
  if (number % 2 == 0) System.out.println (number);
}
```

Or if you don't care about empty lines:

```
while (true) System.out.println (input.nextInt () % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "");
```

EDIT: Same thing for powers of two:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int number;
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print ("Enter a number");
        number = input.nextInt ();
        while ( (number & 1) == 0) number >>= 1;
        if (number == 1) System.out.println ("Perfect divisor.");
    }
```

Comment: This is my other interpretation of his code.  I'm not sure which one is correct (mine or yours)

Comment: Hence I stole yours and pastet it here, too.

Comment: Just switch `number += 2` with `System.out` so that the number doesn't jump one multple of 2 at the beginning

Comment: Which one was the one you were looking for?

Comment: Actually there is a problem. The code needs to excute only multiples of 2 so like 2, 4,8, 16. These are multiples of even numbers etc. So any odd multiple needs to be discarded such as 2*3=6 etc.

I tried placing  if( number%2 ==0) inside the while(true) but it isn't working.

Comment: Then you are talking about powers and not multiples. What would be the expected output for input 13 then?

Comment: It shouldn't spit out anything for 13? Only when it is perfectly divisible by 2.

Comment: OK,so input 13 -> No output. Input 32 -> output "This is a power of 2". Correct?

Comment: yeah. So like if I input 2 it should print all the powers of 2.  Actually forget about inputing any other number. It asks me to print out all the powers of integer 2 in a never ending loop. But the book uses the term multiples instead.

Comment: You change your problem with every comment. But I think you have by now enough code snippets to solve it.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I am confused myself. It never used the term power. It simply asks me to print multiples of 2 such as 2,4,8,16,32 ... going on forever. Thanks.

Comment: And what has the user input to do with that? If I input 2 it prints 2, 4, 8, 16 and if I input 3 it prints 3, 9, 27, 81?

Comment: No , I dont think we are suppose to input anything at all. It only asks us to print multiples for 2. Okay here is it what it says-
 
" Write an application that keeps displaying in the command window the multiples of the integer 2-namely 2.4.8,16,32,64 and so. Yourloop should not terminate."

Comment: There is a maximum size for an integer. There is even a maximum size for a BigInteger. Hence the loop must terminate some time.

Answer (score 0):

An infinite loop does not need a counter. It can be written like this:

```
if((number % 2) != 0) {
    number++;
}

while(true) {
    System.out.println(number);
    number = number + 2;
}
```

**edit:** Added infinitely finding multiples of 2

Comment: `number = number + 2;` can be reduced to `number += 2;`

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised this compiles.

```
x= (++number)
```

has no semi-colon at the end.

also, move the if statement inside of the while. If you are checking for multiples of 2, you will want that check after each iteration of the loop

edit: you changed your original code. Please copy/paste from your source instead of re-typing.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear but may be something like this would help you:

```
Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
int number;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    number=input.nextInt();
    if(number%2==0)
       System.out.println(number);
} while (number > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is a homework question, so perhaps explaining the methodology will help you more than a full answer.

Firstly, you can use a `while` loop to ensure that your code gets executed more than once:

[while loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop)

A while loop will keep executing the code inside it *while the given boolean condition evaluates to true*. So, you can wrap up your code with:

```
while(true) {
//...
}
```

and anything between the brackets will continually execute (line by line) forever.

If you get a number from the user at the beginning of the loop, the loop will stop executing any further code until the user types something (it will be blocked, waiting on IO).

Once you get the number, the loop will start executing the rest of the code, before returning to the top of the loop and repeating the process.

```
while (true) {
//ask user for number

//print out the number

// check that it is even

// print whether it is even or odd
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Fordemo
{


public static void main(String args[])
{

int k,x=0;

for(k=1;k<=10;k++)
{

x=k*2;

System.out.println("multiple of 2 is "+x);

}}}
```

Comment: The OP needs a never ending loop (`do`-`while`), not a `for` loop.